# Cite confidential source

Tags: citations

i'm currently using several construction drawings to extract a note on how a certain design is usually done in the industry. I'm neither allowed to name the specific product nor the company. I guess I can't assume that the extracted information are common knowledge, so a source or a footnote would be required.

How do you typically handle this?

Comment: Do you mean drawings produced by some software product?

Comment: @Buffy Yes, CAD drawings. The used software is not stated though.

Comment: When you say “specific product” is that the software used to produce the drawings or the product which is represented in the drawings. This is an important distiction.

Comment: If your only sources are all proprietary-confidential type things, are you sure it's really all that usual?

Comment: @SolarMike The software itself is unimportant, it's just used to print the design the engineer made up.

Comment: @puppetsock  Good point, but by the amount of competitors in this area, I think I can safely assume that.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably say something like: "A popular CAD* program treats the problem as follows...". Then use the footnote to explain that the program won't or can't be named for legal or other reasons.

In other words, give a generic description but say that it is a specific example meeting that description. Don't give the impression that all do, unless you have evidence of it.